# What is a "static" class?

Tags: c#, static-classes

In C# what is the difference between:

```
public static class ClassName {}
```

And:

```
public class ClassName {}
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

A static class cannot be instantiated, and can contain only static members. Hence, the calls for a static class are as: `MyStaticClass.MyMethod(...)` or `MyStaticClass.MyConstant`.

A non static class can be instantiated and may contain non-static members (instance constructors, destructor, indexers). A non-static member of a non-static class is callable only through an object:

```
MyNonStaticClass x = new MyNonStaticClass(...);
x.MyNonStaticMethod(...);
```

Comment: Internally the compiler marks the class abstract and sealed, and creates a private constructor in the IL code.

Comment: By `members` do you mean everything and anything that can be declared/instantiated inside a class (i.e., nested classes, fields, properties, de/constructors, methods)? They *all* must be declared static?

Comment: @Minh Tran: not instantiated, but declared: yes, excepting destructors and indexers - they cannot be static. And for constructor, you can have only one static ctor, parametereless. Nested classes are by default static members of a class.

Answer (score 75):

Firstly, a comment on an answer asked about what "static" means. In C# terms, "static" means "relating to the type itself, rather than an instance of the type." You access a static member (from another type) using the type name instead of a reference or a value. For example:

```
// Static method, so called using type name
Guid someGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
// Instance method, called on a value
string asString = someGuid.ToString();
```

Now, static classes...

Static classes are usually used as "utility" classes. The canonical example is probably [`System.Math`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.aspx). It doesn't make sense to create an instance of math - it just "is". A few rules (both "can" and "can't"):

- Static classes always derive from `object`. You can't specify a different base type, or make the static class implement an interface.
- Static classes can't have any instance members - all variables, methods etc must be static.
- Static classes can't declare any instance constructors and the compiler *doesn't* create a parameterless constructor by default. (Before static classes came in C# 2.0, people would often create an abstract class with a private constructor, which prevented instantiation. No need here.)
- Static classes are implicitly abstract (i.e. they're compiled to IL which describes an abstract class) but you can't add the `abstract` modifier yourself.
- Static classes are implicitly sealed (i.e. they're compiled to IL which describes an sealed class) but you can't add the `sealed` modifier yourself.
- Static classes *may* be generic.
- Static classes *may* be nested, in either non-static or static classes.
- Static classes *may* have nested types, either non-static or static.
- Only static, top-level non-generic classes can contain extension methods (C# 3.0).

Comment: "Static classes can't declare any constructors "  What about static ctors?

Comment: @Andy: Yes, they can declare static constructors.

Comment: Ok, maybe the statement about not declaring any constructors should be reworded, because it sounds like static ctors aren't an option the way it is now.

Comment: @Andy: Well normally if someone says "constructor" they implicitly mean "instance constructor". I'll edit, but I really don't think it's that confusing.

Comment: How CLR  can be handle the static class and ordinary class?

Comment: @AbiRuban: The same way. The CLR doesn't care about static classes - it just sees a sealed abstract class with no constructors.

Comment: @Jon Skeet thanks i have another que. What is the advantage of static class

Comment: @AbiRuban: Did you try searching the site before asking the question? If you did and you found the answer, there's no need for a comment here. If you didn't find the answer, it should be a new question, not a comment. I'm pretty sure there are other questions on the site though...

Comment: @JonSkeet I searched in Google and stackoverflow(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10717469/what-are-the-advantages-of-non-static-class-over-static-class) but i could not find the correct answer. I need  in depth answer  so only i ask to you. I already posted a question but stackoverflow members closed my question

Comment: @AbiRuban: There are plenty of other questions, such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241339/when-to-use-static-classes-in-c-sharp and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4677221/regarding-static-class-in-c-sharp

Comment: @JonSkeet ok they all are said "static class cannot be instantiated". In my question why we cannot be instantiated. Is anything advantage?

Comment: @JonSkeet I ask anything wrong i am sorry. I am new to software development

Comment: @AbiRuban: Sorry, it's really not appropriate to ask new questions like this in comments. As I say, there are *lots* of other questions which cover this. Static classes allow you to explicitly state the *intention* that you can't create instances of the class. Please read the answers to the other questions *carefully*. (This will be my last comment on this thread.)

Answer (score 7):

```
public static class ClassName {}
```

A static class is just like a global variable: you can use it anywhere in your code without instantiating them.
For example: **ClassName. After the dot operator, you can use any property or function of it.**

```
 public class ClassName {}
```

But if you have non-static class then you need to create an instance of this class.
For example:

```
 ClassName classNameObject = new ClassName();
```

Answer (score 6):

All methods/properties in a static class **must** be static, whereas a 'normal' class can contain a mix of instance and static methods.

Answer (score 6):

A static class also can not be inherited from, whereas a non-static class with static members can be inherited from.

Answer (score 4):

Static class can contain static members only.

Static member can be used without instantiating a class first.

Comment: What is the difference between a static member and a non-static member? Maybe that is what I am missing.

Answer (score 3):

You can't instantiate (create objects of) a static class. And it can only contain static members.

Example: System.Math

Answer (score 2):

Static classes and members are used to create data and methods that can be accessed without creating an instance (using the `new` keyword, they cannot have a constructor) of the class.

Static classes can be declared when there is no dependence on the its own object identity, so a static class must contain only static members.

This classes are loaded by the CLR when the program or namespace containing the class is loaded.

They are also sealed, cannot be inherited from.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/1999-08/01-qa-static2.html - very good article on this. This is for Java. But i think concept should should same in C# too.

Answer (score 1):

**Static variable in c**

a variable local to a class as auto variables
but static variable do not disappear as function is no longer active.Their values persist.If control comes back,static variables have same value

**static function in c**
functions that are not visible to functions in other files.

**static data members in cpp **
data members can be variables or functions in cpp
static applies to both data members
the class itself can be static
"There is only one copy of static data memberss shared by all objects in that class"
static data members can access only static data members

**static class**
this class cannot instantiate objects

Answer (score 0):

Most importantly, "*A static constructor is only called one time, and a static class remains in memory for the lifetime of the application domain in which your program resides.*" - From [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members#:%7E:text=A%20static%20class%20is%20basically,variable%20of%20the%20class%20type.)