# What is better: public static Class with static methods or public Class with static methods?

Tags: class, static, c#-3.0

Regarding class public class declaration, please look at these two pieces of code:

```
public class Helper
{
    public static void CallMeganFox(string phoneNumber)
    { //...
```

and

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static void CallMeganFox(string phoneNumber)
    { //...
```

What is better to use and why?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deciding to make a C# class static](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660094/deciding-to-make-a-c-sharp-class-static)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's "better" in theory to make it explicit that this class is not supposed to be instantiated by making it `static` (second option), because it *communicates intent*¹.

However in such a simple case, from a practical perspective there will be exactly zero difference². Noone's going to look at this class and try to instantiate it.

¹ As Cody Gray points out, it can also help you catch mistakes earlier (e.g. forgetting to make a helper method `static`). While that viewpoint certainly has merit, again the practical difference is going to be negligible: the compiler would complain as soon as you tried to call the method statically in any case.

² Actually, this is not always true. For example, the C# compiler will not let you define extension methods in a non-`static` class -- not because it cannot, but because it wants to nudge you towards a "best practice".

Comment: Agreed; not only does it communicate intent, it prevents mistakes (such as forgetting to declare a newly-added function `static`).

Answer (score 1):

`static` class cannot have non-static methods. If that's what you want - then use it.

More information can be found [in this SO question and answers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660094/deciding-to-make-a-c-sharp-class-static/7660149#7660149)