# Java class which all its methods are static

Tags: java, methods, static

What are the classes in Java which:

1. all its methods are static
2. Does not contain any instance methods

Comment: Aren't 1 and 2 just different ways of saying the same thing?

Comment: Do you mean "utility classes"? Is this a homework question?

Comment: Your question also shows no evidence of prior research

Comment: Need to know any predefined class in Java whos all methods are static.

Comment: What has Google brought you when you searched on this very question? Please show this result in your question and use it to make the question more specific. Note that the site is not here to do your homework for you.

Comment: Searched on google and found nothing.
Therefore I posted my question here.

Sorry if I have asked anything wrong.
I will keep in mind before posting anything here.

Answer (score 3):

[Lombok define it as UtilityClass](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/UtilityClass):

> A utility class is a class that is just a namespace for functions. No instances of it can exist, and all its members are static. For example, java.lang.Math and java.util.Collections are well known utility classes. This annotation automatically turns the annotated class into one.
>
> A utility class cannot be instantiated. By marking your class with @UtilityClass, lombok will automatically generate a private constructor that throws an exception, flags as error any explicit constructors you add, and marks the class final. If the class is an inner class, the class is also marked static.
>
> All members of a utility class are automatically marked as static. Even fields and inner classes.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're describing a [**static class**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/695056/1813169).

While Java does not allow you to explicitly declare a ([*non-nested*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3584113/1813169)) class as `static`, it is still possible to implement this paradigm.