# C# When to use Static Classes as opposed to Instances of Classes?

Tags: c#, static, instance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When to Use Static Classes in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241339/when-to-use-static-classes-in-c)

Questions in the title..........i would greatly appreciate opinions on when it's best to use each?

Regards

Comment: must surely be a dupe?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241339/when-to-use-static-classes-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the case when you don't have access to that different class (see [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)'s answer). However, when you do have access to the code then the rule I use is the following:

Can I get away with using a static class, or do I need to store different data in that class each time?

Hope this helps.

**EDIT**: Disregard the first sentence since [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) deleted his answer.

Answer (score 1):

I use static classes when they just contain fairly simple helper methods. In other cases I use instances of objects, so that I can do dependency injection and write proper unit tests.