# Java generics - ensure static method is implemented

Tags: java, generics

I'm using generics like this: `public class MyList<T>`. Is there any way to ensure that the class represented by T implements a certain static method?

Comment: @Kirk Woll: I'm trying to avoid having to subclass stuff or having to declare methods non-static that really should be static. At the same time, I want to keep my code as concise as possible using generics.

Comment: @user, my point is that even if you *could* add such a constraint, it would be pointless as there is nothing you could do with that ability from within your generic `MyList<T>` in the first place.  You would not be able to invoke those static methods from within your generic list -- you cannot do anything with static members via generic parameters.

Comment: IMHO, your method should not be static. Even if you need a method returning the same value for each instance and not using `this` at all, it shouldn't be static (which took me once long to comprehend). There are in fact just few uses for static methods.

Comment: @Kirk Woll: Basically, I got some very similar classes. Part of these classes is checking whether a given string matches with the required format. I do that checking with a static method. I'm currently implementing the classes using generics. So I have to somehow check the format. I obviously could make the format-checking method non-static but I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Why what? Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3251269/when-to-use-static-classes-and-methods could help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, even without generics there is never a way to ensure a class implements a static method.

You can, however, create a generic static method.

```
public static <T> List<T> makeSingletonList(T item) {
      ArrayList<T> result = new ArrayList<T>();
      result.add(item);
      return result;
}
```

Comment: And put it in the abstract class which your classes need to extend.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately not.

As an alternative, consider whether the static methods of your class belongs in some sort of associated class like a builder:

```
class Person {
    public static Person createFromDatastore(Datastore datastore) { ... }
}
```

It may be better to move the static to a separate class as a non-static method:

```
class PersonBuilder implements Builder<Person> {
     public Person createFromDatastore(Datastore datastore) { ... }
}
```

This means that you can dictate clients of your generic class can now be required to provide it:

```
public class MyList<B extends Builder<T>, T> ...
```