# UWP object reference required from non-static method

Tags: c#, json, http, asynchronous, uwp

I am creating a UWP app, simply put I have an async void GetWeather function that reads  JSON from an API and creates an object. Calling the Forecast.getWeather() function I get the error " object reference required from non-static method". I have done my research but have not found a solution to this with a void method as I don't want to return an object just yet. Also if this is not possible (and maybe a better idea) how would I return the Object so it can be used on many different pages throughout the app or would the object values still be accessible if created in the void method?

## Forecast.cs

```
    class Forecast
{
    public async void GetWeather()
    {
        var uri = new Uri("MY API URI HERE");
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri))
            {
                using (IHttpContent content = response.Content)
                {
                     var json = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
                    Debug.WriteLine("In async method");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

## MainPage

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        Forecast.GetWeather();

    }
}
```

## Weather.cs

```
namespace WeatherForecast
{

public class Main
{
    public double temp { get; set; }
    public double temp_min { get; set; }
    public double temp_max { get; set; }
    public double pressure { get; set; }
    public double sea_level { get; set; }
    public double grnd_level { get; set; }
    public int humidity { get; set; }
    public double temp_kf { get; set; }
}

public class Weather
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string main { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
}

public class Clouds
{
    public int all { get; set; }
}

public class Wind
{
    public double speed { get; set; }
    public double deg { get; set; }
}

public class Snow
{
    public double __invalid_name__3h { get; set; }
}

public class Sys
{
    public string pod { get; set; }
}

public class List
{
    public int dt { get; set; }
    public Main main { get; set; }
    public List<Weather> weather { get; set; }
    public Clouds clouds { get; set; }
    public Wind wind { get; set; }
    public Snow snow { get; set; }
    public Sys sys { get; set; }
    public string dt_txt { get; set; }
}

public class Coord
{
    public double lat { get; set; }
    public double lon { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Coord coord { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string cod { get; set; }
    public double message { get; set; }
    public int cnt { get; set; }
    public List<List> list { get; set; }
    public City city { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the speedy response @John  but that gives an error on the `)` that _A new expression requires (),[], or {} after type_

Comment: oops typo. `(new Forecast()).GetWeather();`

Comment: Perfect thanks that has saved me greatly,also as I am new to UWP would my `result` object created in forecast.cs be available on different pages of my app or is the scope to withen forecast.cs ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your method is not static, so you need to create an instance of the `Forecast` class to access it. You can read more on this in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241899/what-is-the-difference-between-static-methods-in-a-non-static-class-and-static-m) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747116/guidelines-for-when-to-use-static-class-over-instance-class).

The quick solution also would be to make your `Forecast` class static (as long as you don't want to have multiple different instances of it):

```
static class Forecast
{
    public static async void GetWeather()
    {
        var uri = new Uri("MY API URI HERE");
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri))
            {
                using (IHttpContent content = response.Content)
                {
                     var json = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
                    Debug.WriteLine("In async method");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But now we come upon a bigger problem. Your method is `async` and is `async void`. This is something you should do only when absolutely necessary as `async void` methods are so-called *fire-and-forget*. They start, but when they reach the first true *asynchronous* call, they will execute on their own and if something bad happens inside the method (like an exception) you will never know about it until the symptoms start appearing elsewhere in a hard-to-debug way. Also you never know when the `result` is actually ready for you to use.

The best solution is then `Task` return type. This presents a *promise* that the result will be available when the method execution is finished.

```
static class Forecast
{
    public static RootObject Result {get; private set;}

    public static async Task GetWeatherAsync()
    {
        var uri = new Uri("MY API URI HERE");
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uri))
            {
                using (IHttpContent content = response.Content)
                {
                    var json = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    Result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);

                    Debug.WriteLine("In async method");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can see the method is no longer `void` but it still does not return the `RootObject` directly (as you requested, otherwise you could use `Task<RootObject>` to return it). I also added a `Result` property so that the result is accessible when the execution is finished. Because the class is `static`, the property is accessible from anywhere after the `GetWeatherAsync` method call finished.

Now how can you use this? Instead of the constructor you can call the method in `OnNavigatedTo` handler:

```
public override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo( e );
    try
    {
       await Forecast.GetWeatherAsync();
       //after await finishes, Result is ready

       //do something with Forecast.Result
    }
    catch
    {
       //handle any exceptions
    }
}
```

You may notice that I violated the rule that `async` methods should not be `void`. However, in this case, we are dealing with event handler which has a fixed notation so you have no other choice. However, I have added a `try-catch` block so that we can handle any exceptions if they happen.

I recommend reading more on `async-await` in [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async) as it will help you understand the concept much better. I also suggest you to check out more detailed info on instance vs. static to better understand the distinction and when to use each of them.