# C# Cannot Reach Class Elements

Tags: c#, class

It seems like a very simple error, but I could not solve it.
I have created a Class named User in User.cs, and when I instantiate it in another .cs file, it does it, but I cannot either change its properties or reach its properties.

```
User user = new User();
```

I create a new instance like this, but then I cannot reach. For example:

```
user.name
```

The content of User class is the following:

```
public class User
{
    public static string name;
    public static int age;
    public static int height;
    public static int weight;
}
```

What is the reason and how can I solve it?
Thanks

Comment: Please show us the code for the User class

Comment: Could it be that `name` is not `public`? Why did you not specify the exact error you're getting?

Comment: is your string name public? please share User.cs file

Comment: Why are the fields in your `User` class marked as `static`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to Use Static Classes in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241339/when-to-use-static-classes-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created a static object, don't instantiate the class to use it, just do

```
User.name
```

Alternativly remove the static keyword.

The word static means you don't need to make a new insance of the class to access something so  for a class with

```
public Class { 
    public static object myAttribute;
}

Class.myAttribute
```

But if you don't use the static key word

```
public Class { 
    public object myAttribute;
}

Class myClass = new Class();
myClass.myAttribute;
```

You want to use a static value when your value does not depend on any other variables in the same class. When they do depend on varibles (or manipulations of variables) in the same class then use non static.

Answer (score 2):

remove keyword `static` from fields

Comment: It worked. Thanks. Now I got the difference caused by static.

Answer (score 1):

Is `name` public member? Set it public or create a public property to access it...

```
public string Name { get { return name; } }
```

**EDIT:** as `name` is a static member, you cannot write `myUser.name`. It's `User.name`. I think you should remove `static` (and learn some basis...).

What is the error message that occurs during build? It should be clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare name as public in the user class.  For example:

```
public string name { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access static fields from the instance of a class. You can either not declare the fields static:

```
public class User
{
    public string name;
    public int age;
    public int height;
    public int weight; 
...
```

Or you can access the class statically:

```
User.name
```