# What is the difference in use between extension static methods and non-extension static method

Tags: c#, extension-methods

In `class A` I have a method:

```
  public static String GetTimestamp(this DateTime value) {
            return value.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffff");
        }
```

I call it by:

```
        String timeStamp = GetTimestamp(new DateTime());
```

What is the difference in use if that method looked like:

```
  public static String GetTimestamp( DateTime value) {
                return value.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssffff");
            }
```

Comment: I've never seen extension methods used like that. I usually see it like `date.GetTimestamp();` or something along those lines, but they're both acceptable.

Answer (score 4):

The point of an extension method is that you could have called it like:

```
String timeStamp = new DateTime().GetTimestamp();
```

to the same effect. That’s the only change.

Comment: That what I thought but it didn't work: `System.... DateTime()` does not contain definition.... That is what I get.

Comment: Ok I get: Error 1 Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class C:\Users\R\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\HomeSecurity\HomeSecurity\VideoStream.cs 12 26 HomeSecurity

Comment: Well, is your class `static`? You need a `static class Something { … }` for extension methods.

Comment: In C# if I make class static does it have any drawbacks?

Comment: Ok I see IT HAS. I can't create class extension.

Comment: Don’t just make your containing class static or anything like that. Make a new class.

Comment: @Yoda, If you're interested in static classes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241339/when-to-use-static-classes-in-c-sharp

Comment: Btw, you can do as @minitech suggested and create a static class *only* for extension methods.

Answer (score 2):

Extension Methods are intended to be used as "if they were" regular instance methods of their target types:

```
var timeStamp = new DateTime().GetTimestamp();
```

other than that, there is no difference.

---

They were introduced in C# 3.0 to create the beautiful syntax we normally see in LINQ today, such as:

```
  var soldProducts = customers.Where(x => x.IsActive)
                              .SelectMany(x => x.Orders)
                              .Where(x => x.Status == OrderStatus.Completed)
                              .Select(x => x.Product)
                              .ToList;
```

without extension methods, this syntax would not be possible and would require many regular method calls:

```
var activecustomers = Enumerable.Where(customers, x => x.IsActive);
var orders = Enumerable.SelectMany(activecustomers, x => x.Orders);
var completed = Enumerable.Where(orders, x => x.Status == OrderStatus.Completed);
var products = Enumerable.Select(completed, x => x.Product);
var soldProducts = Enumerable.ToList(products);
```

Not to mention that `type inference` is also playing a big part here, since most of these methods in `System.Linq.Enumerable` are actually generic methods with one or several type parameters, but the C# compiler is smart enough to infer the generic type parameters and remove the need to explicitly specify them.

Answer (score 2):

With the extension method version, you can also call it with

```
dateTime.GetTimeStamp()
```

if you've includeded the namespace it's declared in.

Comment: Ok how to include that namespace?

Comment: @yoda if class `A` is defined in `namespace MyNamespace` then just `using MyNamespace` in the code where you're trying to use the extension.

Comment: I am using this extension just under the place it is defined. VS2013 tells me that `DateTime` does not contain definition of `GetTimeStamp`.

Comment: Ok I get: Error 1 Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class C:\Users\R\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\HomeSecurity\HomeSecurity\VideoStream.cs 12 26 HomeSecurity

Answer (score 2):

Extension methods allow you to treat them as though they were a method *inside* of the type in question.  So in your first example, that method can be treated as though it is a method inside of DateTime.  so you could do something like this:

```
var foo = new DateTime();
var timestamp = foo.GetTimestamp();
```