# Why a class with only static methods is used?

Tags: c#, .net, class, oop

I want to know the reasons for creating a class with only static methods, for example the `Console` or the `Convert` classes. The only reason I can think of is to group related functions together, so how is this different from a namespace.

Comment: static classes are basically a way to implement a singleton.  Also, used to defined extensions to pre-existing classes.

Comment: Note that in C# every method, property, event etc. must live inside a type, like a `class`. It is not allowed to have a method as a direct member of a namespace. But I can see why you compare static classes to namespaces.

Comment: c# has one more usage: Extension methods must be declared in static classes. E.g.: System.Linq.Enumerable

Comment: @Richard So what exactly is the difference between a static class and a Singleton? The Singleton is only initialized when called, while the static class is initialized at start?

Comment: @Kilazur: See the answer on the comment below my answer.

Comment: @Kilazur static class can not be inherited where on other side singleton can be inherited.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When to Use Static Classes in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241339/when-to-use-static-classes-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @RichardSchneider _"static classes are basically a way to implement a singleton"_ - are you sure?  _[A singleton allows access to a **single created instance** - that instance (or rather, a reference to that instance) **can be passed** as a parameter to other methods, and **treated as a normal object**.  A static class allows only **static methods**.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/519520/difference-between-static-class-and-singleton-pattern)_

Answer (score 6):

There is just one console, so why do you need to instantiate a class? There is no need for it. That is just one reason. (This is just a way to implement the singleton design pattern)

Another reason could be that the methods are not related to an instance, they are just helper method, like `Convert.XXX`. Related to this are extension methods, that are obligated to be in a `static` class, also since they are not related to an instance of the class they are contained in.

Namespaces can't contain methods, so you need a class to wrap them in.

Comment: As I asked in the question's comments, what exactly is the difference between a static class and a Singleton?

Comment: @Kilazur: You can't pass an instance of a static class into a method, you can pass in a singleton instantiated class.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Passing a singleton class to a method makes no sense.

Comment: I agree it usually doesn't. It does if you have to pass it to another method that isn't yours and you want to enforce singleton on your side.

Answer (score 3):

A good answer to this is this interview to Stroustrup, talking about invariants. If a class doesn't modify any of its properties, or doesn't have a property you may want static methods.

http://slesinsky.org/brian/code/stroustrup_on_invariants.html

Comment: That's an interesting way to put it.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the point. Maybe it becomes clear when u see when we use such classes in our very big project cluster:

We use such a class e.g. as `Utilities` and `Constants` functionality in our project cluster.

That means you can use such utilities like as `ConvertXFromYtoZ` or `WriteDebug` anytime without taking care of the instance of the object.

We use also 'a lot' of different constants. Its very fine to have them in  one static place: `Constants.MyArea_Type_Foo`.

By the way, it is also nice to have the `static` `Regex.Match` class. I nearly never use the dynamic `Regex` class.