# How to find controls value inside static method

Tags: c#

Inside static method am notable to get hidden field values:

```
private static void GetDetails()
{
    Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
    HiddenField hdnUserID = (HiddenField)page.FindControl("hdnUserID");
    txtAccreditation.Text = hdnUserID.Value ; //  here hdnUserID.Value is null why ?? 
}
```

Comment: Just thinking about something: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241339/when-to-use-static-classes-in-c-sharp;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

```
  Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
  TextBox TextBox1 = (TextBox)page.FindControl("TextBox1");

  TextBox TextBox2 = (TextBox)page.FindControl("TextBox2");
```

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you need to change your code to something like this:

Change your code as followed

```
private static void GetDetails(HiddenField field)
{     
   txtAccreditation.Text = field.Value ;
}
```

and call it like this

```
Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
HiddenField hdnUserID = (HiddenField)page.FindControl("hdnUserID");
YourClassName.GetDetails(hdnUserId);
```

What I do not understand is why would you call it through a static operation.

I would assume you create something more like the following code:

```
private static string GetDetails(HiddenField field)
{     
   return field.Value ;
}
```

This would result in the following code: This code will not be present inside the static function.

```
Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
HiddenField hdnUserID = (HiddenField)page.FindControl("hdnUserID");
txtAccreditation.Text = YourClassName.GetDetails(hdnUserId);
```

meaning you could actually use the code everywhere else