# Calling method from different class in same library, errors about object reference

Tags: c#, class, dll

I wrote code for a new library, most of the code is located under

```
public class Locked
```

Most graphical functions are in there.
However i also provide some specific exotic maths as a separate name-space in the same dll as Magic Math, those functions are not private just as public as every function under Locked.

```
public class MagicMath
```

Some functions inside the Locked class require the MagicMath
So i call them as

```
MagicMath.ResizeDataSet(...
```

This gives an error An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property

```
   'MagicMath.ResizeDataSet( SortedDictionary <int, List<int>>, int, int)'
```

I'm kinda confused here, as those functions in MagicMath are recognised, their parameters gets accepted, i only get a redline under the function text (ResizeDataSet) when called from within code in the class Locked..
Whats wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either set the methods inside 'Locked' that call 'MagicMath' to `static` as well as the MagicMath methods that are called or create an instance of MagicMath.

See what [static](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx) means and when to use it in the words of Microsoft.

> Use the static modifier to declare a static member, which belongs to
>   the type itself rather than to a specific object. The static modifier
>   can be used with classes, fields, methods, properties, operators,
>   events, and constructors, but it cannot be used with indexers,
>   destructors, or types other than classes.

Comment: hm adding static like 'public static SortedDictionary<int, List<int>> ResizeDataSet(SortedDictionary<int, List...' did indeed resolve it.
I wonder how should it be handled in libraries with mulitple namespaces

ea myLib.Graphics.Draw and myLib.Statistics.GlobalMean  Should one of the name spaces (Graphics / Statistics ) be full of static functions then ?.still a bit confused here..

Comment: Well that depends on how it's going to be used. There's no hard and fast rule. Hopefully this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241339/when-to-use-static-classes-in-c-sharp If your initial problem has been fixed then please mark this as the answer.

Comment: ah i think i understand now, the graphics class is al surounded around a graphical object (main code creates an instance of it), while the Math functions are just functions, not objects..