# From MainWindow.xaml.cs class, why I am unable to access a custom property of App.xam.cs class

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In `MainWindow.xaml.cs` class, when trying to get access to my property `Name` inside `App.xaml.cs` class, I'm getting the error:

> 'App' does not contain a definition for 'Name'.

Why?

**Remark**: I'm working a scenario similar to [this one](https://www.rhyous.com/2010/02/19/how-to-process-command-line-parameters-or-arguments-in-a-wpf-application/). But author there is using a global variable, and as we know, in most cases, [using properties is preferred over global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/295104/1232087). So, I'm trying property in my case.

**App.xaml.cs**:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private string[] name;
    public string[] Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string[] myArray = App.Name //VS2019 Intellisense gives the error: 'App' does not contain a definition for 'Name'
    }
}
```

Comment: My bad, as `@TamBui` pointed it, I forgot to use the static keyword in the property declaration. More on the topic, interesting debate [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241339/when-to-use-static-classes-in-c-sharp). Specifically the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241339/when-to-use-static-classes-in-c-sharp#comment103027740_241339) from @ashveli.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the Name property static because it doesn't look like you are instantiating your App class inside your MainWindow class at all.

```
......
......
public partial class App : Application
{
    private static string[] name;
    public static string[] Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; }
    }
......
......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`public string[] Name` is an *instance* property of App, so you need to get a reference to instance before accesing data.

the running WPF instance can be obtained from static property Application.Current (requires cast)

```
var app = Application.Current as App;
string[] myArray = app.Name;
```