# C# Best way to create or access a data container

Tags: c#, performance, memory

So I have the following ways of accessing/creating a list

```
public class TestClass
{
    private static List<String> stringList1 = new List<String> {
        "string1",
        "string2",
        "string3",
        "string4"};

    public void TestFunc(String str)
    {
        if (stringList1.Contains(str)) //1st way of accessing list
        {
           //do something
        }
        if (getList2().Contains(str)) //2nd way of accessing list
        {
           //do something
        }
    }

    private List<String> getList2()
    {
        return new List<String> {
        "string1",
        "string2",
        "string3",
        "string4"};
    }
}
```

Which would be the best way in terms of memory/speed etc...?

Comment: you are creating a new list, hence more garbage in `getList2`

Comment: Did you mean for the `getList2` method to return `stringList1` instead of creating its own object? If no, I'm not sure what you're getting at, as you're comparing apples and oranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may be a dick, but... it depends. Depending on how you use those classes they would perform the same both alternatives or they could perform worse.

If you have this class:

```cs
public class TestStatic
{
    private static List<String> stringList1 = new List<String>() 
    {
        "string1",
        "string2",
        "string3",
        "string4"
    };

    public static bool Test(String str)  //1st way of accessing list
    {
        if (stringList1.Contains(str))
        {
           return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
public class TestInstance
{
    private List<String> getList2()
    {
        return new List<String>()
        {
           "string1",
           "string2",
           "string3",
           "string4"
        };
    }
    public bool Test(String str)
    {
        List<String> myList = getList2();
        if (myList.Contains(str))
        {
           return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

If the code in both classes is executed once, both would perform the same (both would allocate the list in memory once).

If the code is executed more times, the static version would perform better because each time `new List<String>` is called more memory is allocated (aka worse performance) and `static` data is not instance specific, so no extra memory is used.

You can dig into more advanced answers in similar question like this one that has really good (albeit more advanced) answers. [When to use static classes in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/241339/when-to-use-static-classes-in-c-sharp)